# Problem with CORS in Nest.js app after deployment on Vercel

Tags: node.js, deployment, cors, nestjs, vercel

POST request in my Nest.js app not working after deployment on Vercel and I receive CORS error, but cors in my app is enable and when I send GET request all working. When I test my request in postman all working. I am not sure but maybe this error can happen through that I use React Query or problem with vercel and I not right deployment my app.

I receive such error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://server-store.vercel.app/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://next-store-liard-three.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And I enabled CORS such method:

```
app.enableCors({
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://next-store-liard-three.vercel.app'],
        allowedHeaders: ['Accept', 'Content-Type'],
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
        preflightContinue: false,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
        credentials: true,
    });
```

This is my file vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "next-store-server",
    "buildCommand": "npm start",
    "installCommand": "npm install",
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "dist/main.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "dist/main.js",
            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also I try enable CORS other way, but it is not help me.

I try enable CORS, such method:

```
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

On client I using Next.js, reactQuery and axios for sending request

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FAuth, IUser } from "./Auth.types";

const AuthService = {
    async registration(dto: IUser) {
        const { data } = await axios.post<FAuth>(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API_URL}/api/auth/registration`,
            dto,
        );
        return data;
    },

    async login(dto: IUser) {
        const { data } = await axios.post<FAuth>(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_API_URL}/api/auth/login`, dto);
        return data;
    },
};
```

This my custom useMutation hooks

```
export const useRegistration = () =>
    useMutation((dto: Omit<IUser, "_id">) => AuthService.registration(dto), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success("Success", {
                theme: "colored",
            });
        },
        onError: (data: any) => {
            toast.error(data.response.data.message, {
                theme: "colored",
            });
        },
    });

export const useLogin = () =>
    useMutation((dto: Omit<IUser, "_id">) => AuthService.login(dto), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success("Success", {
                theme: "colored",
            });
        },
        onError: (data: any) => {
            toast.error(data.response.data.message, {
                theme: "colored",
            });
        },
    });
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the client code responsible for sending the problematic request.

Comment: I added necessary client code.

Answer (score 6):

Try to add "OPTIONS" into methods, this worked for me

vercel.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "src/main.ts", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't tried this before, thanks a lot.

Comment: Not work for me